# SI subscription to multiple mqtt topics

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

I'm trying to learn how to handle **MQTT Messages** in **Spring-Integration**. 
Have created a converter, that subscribes with a single MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter per MQTT Topic for consuming and converting the messages.

The problem is our data provider is planning to "speed-up"  publishing messages on his side. So instead of having a few(<=10) topics each of which has messages with about 150 fields it is planned to publish each of those fields to the separate MQTT topic.

This means my converter would have to consume ca. 1000 mqtt topics, but I do not know whether:

1. Is spring-integration still a good choice for it. Cause afaik. the mentioned adapter uses the PAHO MqttClient that will consume the messages from all of the topics it is subscribed to in one single thread and creating 1000 instances of those adapters is an overkill.
2. If we stick further to spring-integration and use the provided components, would it be a good idea to create a single inbound adapter for all of the fields, that previously were in messages of one topic but moving the conversion away from the adapter bean to a separate bean ( that does the conversion) connected with an executer-channel to the adapter and thus executing the conversion of those fields on some threadpool in parallel.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your idea makes sense.

For that purpose you need to implement a *passthrough* `MqttMessageConverter` and provide an `MqttMessage` as a `payload` and `topic` as a header:

```
public class PassThroughMqttMessageConverter implements MqttMessageConverter {

    @Override
    public Message<?> toMessage(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(mqttMessage)
                .setHeader(MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC, topic)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromMessage(Message<?> message, Class<?> targetClass) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> toMessage(Object payload, MessageHeaders headers) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

So, you really will be able to perform a target conversion downstream, after a mentioned `ExecutorChannel` in the custom `transformer`.

You also may consider to implement a custom `MqttPahoClientFactory` (an extension of the `DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory` may work as well) and provide a custom `ScheduledExecutorService` to be injected into the `MqttClient` you are going create in the `getClientInstance()`.

Comment: Thanks Artem! Actually you have already provided us with the DefaultPahoMessageConverter in the Framework, that sets the headers needed(see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-mqtt/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mqtt/support/DefaultPahoMessageConverter.java#L223)).  I am more concerned whether the single subscription of the adater to multiple topics will be enough  to consume all of those messages, eventually flying in in parallel.  Could you please evolve a bit on your last idea of MqttPahoClientFactory .

Comment: Well, I've looked into the Paho client and it doesn't look like we can parallel there with a custom executor. Only a single polling task is going to be started over there anyway. So, the best way for now is to parallel afterward like your original idea with an `ExecutorChannel`.

Comment: Of course, you still can use a `DefaultPahoMessageConverter` if you are OK with all `MqttMessage`s be transformed the same way. Otherwise just postpone it downstream, e.g. with the router.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, PAHO has a single thread for consuming topics that is the main concern. Ok, will try the ExecutorChannel approach.